# XCode 7.2 -- How to accomplish the layout below using Auto Layout

Tags: xcode, autolayout, constraints

Trying to accomplish the layout below using Auto Layout and settings constraints.

[image: Desired layout]

The layout itself is comprised of four UIViews (top and bottom ones occupying the full width of the screen, the two middle ones side by side each taking half the width).

However, after many tutorials on Auto Layout and Setting constraints, the closest I can get to my desired result is the two images below:

[image: Incorrect layout 1]

OR

[image: Incorrect Layout 2]

I've played with the constraints of all the individuals views until all orange and red marks/lines disappeared and only blue ones remained, but I cannot get to the desired result.

Any ideas how this can accomplished using Auto Layout and constraints?

Comment: Hi, Have you accomplished this ?

Comment: What is that white polyline in your first image?

Comment: Just a gap in the drawing. It's a poorly drawn image as it being perfect is not necessary to convey the message of the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For this layout you will need 5 UIViews.
- For the first view `(RGB: 233,132,125)` you need to set **top**, **trailing** and **leading** constraints and make its **height** *0.3% of the Superview*.
- For the second view you will need a main view , which can have **height** of approximately 60 to 80 and it will have **vertical spacing** from its above view and **leading** and **trailing** constraints.
- Now in this view , you will have its *two sub views* `[RGB :220,250,138 and RGB :152,250,253 ]` (You can take UIButtons or UIViews or UILabels, whatever you want).
- For both of these subviews its **height** will be *equal to its parent view* and **width** will be *half of its superview*, as well as **vertically center** in the super view and **trailing space** for the *X-Position*.
- And for the last view `(RGB : 204,135,248)` you have to bound them with **top**, **bottom**, **leading** and **trailing** spaces.

I know this theoretical description will confuse you so check out these stuff in the video Here : https://youtu.be/XUh1n7X8ZRY

You can adjust heights as you need for your views.

Comment: I was hoping the answer contained only the original four views, auto layout, and their constraints.

Comment: So by video you will have now the basic idea right ? Or you need more demonstration ?

Comment: I get the idea.  Thank you for taking the time to answer.